The left shift map and its image.
Let $X\subset{\mathbb{R}^{\infty}}$ be the space of convergent real sequences and let $L\colon{X}\to{X}$ be the operator such that $$L(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)=(x_2,x_3,x_4,\ldots),\quad\forall\bar{x}=(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)\in X.$$ Now, define the operator $$T(\bar{x})=\lim_{n\to\infty}L^{n}(\bar{x}),\quad\forall\bar{x}=(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)\in X,$$ where $L^{n}(\bar{x})=\underbrace{(L\circ\cdots\circ L)}_{n-times}(\bar{x}).$ Show that T is linear and calculate its range.
My attempt: Indeed, let $\bar{x},\bar{y}\in X$ and let $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}.$ Then $$\begin{align*}
T(\alpha\bar{x}+\bar{y})&=\lim_{n\to\infty}L^{n}(\alpha\bar{x}+\bar{y})& \text{The definition of $T$}\\\\
 &= \lim_{n\to\infty}[\alpha L^{n}(\bar{x})+L^{n}(\bar{y})] &\text{$L$ is a linear transformation}\\\\
 &= \alpha\lim_{n\to\infty} L^{n}(\bar{x})+\lim_{n\to\infty}L^{n}(\bar{y}) & \text{$L^{n}(\bar{x}),L^{n}(\bar{y})\in X,\quad\forall n\in\mathbb{N},$ and the limit operation is linear}\\\\
 &= \alpha T(\bar{x})+T(\bar{y}) & \text{The definition of $T$}
\end{align*}
$$
now, the image of T is $$Im(T)=\{\lim_{n\to\infty}L^{n}(\bar{x})\colon\bar{x}\in X\}.$$
What shape does $\{\lim_{n\to\infty}L^{n}(\bar{x})\colon\bar{x}\in X\}$ have?

I claim that ${\rm Im} T$ is equal to the set of constant sequences $(x, x, x, \dots)$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}$ - we will call this set $A$.
($A \subseteq {\rm Im} T$) This is trivial; any sequence $(x, x, x, \dots) \in A$ is a fixed point of $T$.
(${\rm Im} T \subseteq A$) Let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^+} \in {\rm Im} T$. Then $T (x_n) = (x_0, x_0, x_0, \dots)$, where $x_0$ is the limit of $(x_n)$ (i.e., $(x_n) \to x_0$) because for any $i \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, we have
$$(T (x_n))_i = \lim_{j \to \infty} x_{i + j} = \lim_{k \to \infty} x_k = x_0$$
The first equality above is justified by the fact that convergence of sequences in $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ is pointwise when it is equipped with the (usual) product topology (you may want to explicitly show this fact).

Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary. For $\bar x\in X$ exists some $x\in \mathbb R$ and $N\in \mathbb N$ with $|x_n-x|<\frac\epsilon4$ for all $n\geq N$. You can now use this:
\begin{align*}L^n(\bar x)\in \{\bar y\in X\colon |x- y_k|<\frac\epsilon4\; \forall k\in \mathbb N\}\; n\geq N.\label{gl1}\tag1\end{align*}
So let $\bar y\in \text{Im}(T)$ be arbitrary. Assume $\bar y$ is not constant, i.e. there are $i,j\in \mathbb N$ with $|y_i-y_j|>\epsilon$. Now let $\bar x\in X$ be a pre-image of $\bar y$. Then \eqref{gl1} applies  in particular, i.e.:
$$\epsilon<|y_i-y_j|\leq |x -y_i|+|x-y_j|<\frac\epsilon4+\frac\epsilon4=\frac\epsilon2.$$ Contradiction.
